# Variables being changed by TeamSpeak API for PHP

Tags: php, teamspeak

I'm developing a tool for a website and I came up with an odd problem, or better, an odd situation.

I'm using the code bellow to retrieve data from the TeamSpeak server. I use this info to build a profile on a user.

```php
$ts3 = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://dadada:dadada@dadada:1234/");
// Get the clients list
$a=$ts3->clientList();
// Get the groups list
$b=$ts3->ServerGroupList();
// Get the channels list
$c=$ts3->channelList();
```

Now, the odd situation is that the output of this code block:

```
// Get the clients list
$a=$ts3->clientList();
// Get the groups list
$b=$ts3->ServerGroupList();
// Get the channels list
$c=$ts3->channelList();
echo "<pre>";print_r($a);die();
```

(Notice the **print_r**)
Is totally different from the output of this code block:

```
// Get the clients list
$a=$ts3->clientList();
// Get the groups list
#$b=$ts3->ServerGroupList();
// Get the channels list
#$c=$ts3->channelList();
echo "<pre>";print_r($a);die();
```

What I mean is, the functions I call after `clientList()` (which output I store in the variable `$a`) are changing that variable's contents. This is, they're kind of appending their output to the variable.

I've never learned PHP professionally, I'm just trying it out... Am I missing something about this language that justifies this behavior? If I am, what can I do to stop it?

Comment: Seems really strange. Try repeat the line print_r  after the first function and then after every other function just to study exactly how the values change when they're run. Also, have you run the same line but printing $b on the line after printing $a. Is $b showing correct values?

Comment: Well, the output takes up to 14MB, so analysing it is complicated..

Because I'm calling `ServerGroupList()` after `clientList()`, the output is always modified. But if I only call the function `ServerGroupList()`, it's output is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You're seeing parts of the "Object" in Object Oriented Programming

`$ts3` represents an Object containing all the information needed, along with some methods (or functions) that let you get data from the object. Some of these methods will do different things to the object itself, in order to retrieve additional data needed for a particular method call.

Consider the following simple Object:

- Bike

  - color
  - gears
  - function __construct($color, $gears)
  - `this.color = $color; this.gears = $gears`
  - function upgrade()
  - `this.headlight = true; this.gears = 10;`

Now, when you first create it, it only has two properties:

```
$myBike = new Bike('red',5);
// $myBike.color = 'red';
// $myBike.gears = 5;
```

...but once you upgrade, properties have changed, and new ones are added.

```
$myBike->upgrade();
// $myBike.color = 'red';
// $myBike.gears = 10;
// $myBike.headlight = true;
```

## Objects usually pass references rather than copying data, in order to save memory.

...but if you want to make sure that you're getting a copy that won't change (i.e. does not use data references to the `$ts3` object), clone the variable.

```
$a = clone($ts3->clientList());
```

Be warned, this will effectively double the memory and processor usage for that variable.